# During Groovy AST Transformation, some FieldNodes wrongly say they have 0 annotations

Tags: groovy, abstract-syntax-tree

Some FieldNodes wrongly say they have 0 annotations during an AST Transformation.  My AST Transformation is during the CLASS_GENERATION phase.  Why does it do this, and how can I get the missing annotations to show up?

EDIT: The problem mainly seems to happen on super classes of the class that the AST Transformation is running on.

Answer (score 0):

Why CLASS_GENERATION? Are you just analyzing the code? Nevertheless, I haven't heard anyone using this phase for a transform.

A general guideline is to use phase CONVERSION for transforms that don't need much semantic (e.g type) information, and phase CANONICALIZATION for the rest.

GroovyConsole's AST browser (open with CTRL+T) is a handy tool to get an idea of what the AST looks like after each phase. Maybe it will help you find the problem.

Comment: Yes, I am just analyzing the code. I chose class generation because I read the the later phases have more info in the AST tree. I have used the AST browser, but I don't think it displays info about annotations.

Comment: The AST browser does show AnnotationNode's on the right-hand side. You can't drill down further, but you should be able to get some information out of that. Again, CLASS_GENERATION is the wrong phase. If you need as much information as possible, use CANONICALIZATION.